# Removing previous duplicate entry in a linked list

Tags: c, list, linked-list

I have the following structure for my linked list.

```
typedef struct value value;

struct value{
  value* prev;
  value* next;
  int value;
};

...
//ent = entry
if(entry_head == NULL) { 
 entry_head = ent;
 entry_tail = ent;
 entry_tail->prev = NULL;
}
else { // add to top
  ent -> next = entry_head;
  ent -> prev = NULL;
  entry_head -> prev = ent;
  entry_head = ent;
}
```

This gives me the results:

```
Input: a       Result: b
       b               a
```

However when I input two of the same variables, I want to delete the previous variable and have the newly input variable only. ie.

```
Input: a // old    Result: a // new   Actual Result: a // new
       a // new                                      a // old
```

How do I modify this so that It removes the older variable?

Comment: Do you really need to remove the first one? Alternative approach is to not add the second one. But it depends on what your requirements are.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the add node code, in the part of the function that deals with all nodes added to a non NULL list.

```
value *tmp =head ;
while(tmp!=NULL) {
  if(tmp->Value== newval) break;
  tmp=tmp->next;
}
If(tmp!=NULL) return 0;
// add node here

return  1
```

Alternatively after adding a node, create a similar while loop.

For every node in the list all nodes after this have to be compared and removed. This will be in efficient.

To remove a node all you do is some pointer twizzling , then free the node if no longer needed to avoid memory leaks

```
// a->B->c
//  <- <-

value *save=a->next;

a->Next=save->next;

// node c

Save->Next->prev=save->prev;


free(save);
```

This code hasn't been tested, I have no linux on my phone.